# Building with Gradle Throws MalformedJsonException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Whenever I try to build my project with Gradle, I get this error

```
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:310)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ResourceException: Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:164)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:104)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:243)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:219)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:208)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:54)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter.end(MergedResourceWriter.java:129)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.DataMerger.mergeData(DataMerger.java:291)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.ResourceMerger.mergeData(ResourceMerger.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeResources.doFullTaskAction(MergeResources.java:157)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:117)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergeWriter.end(MergeWriter.java:50)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLog.getWholeFileMap(MergingLog.java:128)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLog.logCopy(MergingLog.java:88)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLog.logCopy(MergingLog.java:98)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:215)
    at com.android.ide.common.res2.MergedResourceWriter$1.call(MergedResourceWriter.java:171)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLogPersistUtil.loadFromSingleFile(MergingLogPersistUtil.java:293)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLog$1.load(MergingLog.java:55)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLog$1.load(MergingLog.java:52)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1505)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1386)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:572)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.blame.MergingLogPersistUtil.loadFromSingleFile(MergingLogPersistUtil.java:266)
    ... 14 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I have been working on this project for almost a year now, this is the first time I've seen this issue building with Gradle. Google doesn't return any helpful results either.

My computer's harddrive stopped responding so I had to do a force shutdown while Android Studio was open, and that might have something to do with the issue.

Steps taken:

- Restart Android Studio
- Invalidate Caches and Restart
- Delete .gradle folder in my home directory

This is very aggravating, and I can't seem to find a fix for this. Thank you for the help!

Comment: For me the problem was related to some kind of `AndroidSDK/analytics.settings` file, but using `gradle assembleDebug` from command line worked for the second try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by deleting the project directory and re-importing the project from an older build off of Github. This is not a very good solution, but it's the only one that worked. I was fortunate enough to have my code backed up on Github

Answer (score 31):

Did you try cleaning the project and Re-running again?

Answer (score 9):

This should work:

1. Delete .gradle folder from the workspace.
2. Restart Android Studio.
3. Build -> Clean Project.

Comment: not workin not even app compile i am getting app at compile time

Comment: build succesfuly when i was delete the .gradle folder. Thanks this tip.

Answer (score 5):

You just have to click on build -> Rebuild. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

Build -> Clean Project. and than Built -> Rebuilt Project

Answer (score 2):

Not a real solution, but I switched the build variant from `debug` to `release` and it is able to complete building correctly.

So switching build variant can help you build anyway, if the `debug` one is not a priority.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution will be to import the project to Android Studio again, either by checking out the source to a clean location or by just removing the .idea directory at the root of the project, and reimporting.

Of course, backup first.

Also, another idea can be to first restart the computer. If it's Windows, in some cases I've seen some file locked causing strange behaviors because of that.

Comment: Tried re-importing and restarting my PC, both didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

### For Firebase android Projects,

If you are using Firebase in your Mobile app.

download the `google-services.json` file and put it inside the `/app` folder and run the project again.

Comment: not workin not even app compile i am getting app at compile time

Answer (score 0):

For Cordova projects, first save (or get if you haven't it yet) the `google-services.json` file, aswell other configurations you may have made to the Android platform folder, and run:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

Afterwards, add it up again:

```
cordova platform add android
```

Save your `google-services.json`file in the `platforms/android/app` folder, and then try building the APK. It worked for me, for fixing the error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Malformed root json
```

Answer (score -1):

Build => Clean project
Wait till sync
Build => Rebuild project
Restart the android studio