# Why I am getting MalformedJsonExection?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtimeexception, building

I'm working on a app project that uses Firebase Auth, Database and Storage. I've created the project on February, and, before this morning, it worked fine, without errors. Since this morning, I have :

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

The last modification was about design, xml files, and the last build was successfully done, just after the last java change. I changed nothing in Gradle for a month ago...
This error appears while building for apk, and now I've it each time I start the project. And I don't know why...
So I ask about it : for you, What is the cause ?

If you need more details, I will answer.

Thanks in advance !

(I'm french, and I'm in highschool, so sorry for mistakes...)

Comment: check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284874/building-with-gradle-throws-malformedjsonexception

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I haven't found it before ! It works perfectly ! @LeviAlbuquerque

Comment: @NoahReboul you can close this question by prefix with [closed]